# php - Updating a row in MySQL through single button

Tags: php

I have a button, it is inside a while loop that displays all data in the table. 
NOTE: All data in the table displays fine.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs_admin))
                {
<form class='form-horizontal' method='post' action='check_managedBorrow.php'>
    <input type='hidden' class='form-control' name=".$row['borrow_id']." id=".$row['borrow_id']." placeholder='Quantity'>
    <td><button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Confirm</button></td>
                }
```

But in the `check_managedBorrow.php` it gives me an error that it is not define. How can I put the specific `borrow_id` for each loop, so that I can UPDATE them? 
 PS. Any method will do as long as the `borrow_id` is specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Input element needs a consistent name in order to read the value again in your `check_managedBorrow.php`

```
<input type='hidden' class='form-control' name="BorrowID" value=".$row['borrow_id']." placeholder='Quantity'>
```

You should be able to access the value as `$_POST['BorrowID']` in the receiving file `check_managedBorrow.php`

There is also the closing `</form>` tag missing

Comment: Worked for me! Just a little confuse if its the closing `</form>` tag.